# Negative lookahead alternative

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

For a URL pattern such as this one:

```
/detail.php?a=BYGhs5w8e9o&b=234844617545&h=9827a
```

I would like Google Analytics to match only the URL's with the `a` and `b` parameters in it:

```
/orderdetail.php?a=BYGhs5w8e9o&b=234844617545
```

And thus strip out:

```
&h=9827a
```

The main goal is to be able to setup a goal in Google Analytics which covers only the `a` and `b` parameters and ignores the `h` parameter.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without a negative lookahead?

Comment: Do you mean the goal should not fire if the "h" parameter is present (else the goal will ignore the parameter in any case) ?

Answer (score 1):

Standard regular expressions do not need negative lookahead for this. Just do a match and replace. Searching for:

```
(/detail.php\?a=\w+&b=\w+)&h=\w+
```

and replacing with `\1` works with the regular expressions in Notepad++ version 6.5.5. Google's regular expressions may be subtly different.

The above works by surrounding the wanted text with capturing braces and leaving the unwanted part outside. The `?` needs escaping as un-escaped it means the previous item (ie the `p`) is optional. The `\w` sequence mean any "word" character so `\w+` means a word.